# Choosing a dominated sequence with certain properties

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $\{d_{m}\}_{m\in{\bf{Z}}^{n}}$ of nonnegative numbers with $d_{m}\rightarrow 0$ as $|m|\rightarrow\infty$, I am looking for a sequence $\{a_{j}\}_{j\in{\bf{Z}}}$ such that the product $a_{m_{1}}\cdots a_{m_{n}}\geq d_{(m_{1},...,m_{n})}$ and $a_{j}\rightarrow 0$ as $|j|\rightarrow\infty$, does anyone here know how to construct explicitly such a sequence $\{a_{j}\}_{j\in{\bf{Z}}}$?

Comment: What do you mean by $a_{m_1}\cdots  a_{m_n}$? Is that the product? And what does $d_{(m_1,...,m_n)}$ mean ?

Comment: The first one is product of numbers. For the $(m_{1},...,m_{n})$, note that $m=(m_{1},...,m_{n})$ is a $n$-tuple of integers.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $|(m_1, \dots, m_n)|:= \max_{i=0}^n |m_i|$.

Then we can take an increasing sequence $(M_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{N}$ s.t. 
\begin{eqnarray}
|m|\geq M_k \Rightarrow d_m < \frac{1}{k^n}.
\end{eqnarray}

Let $X:=\max\{1, \max_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^n}d_m\}^{1/n}$ and put
\begin{eqnarray}
a_j :=
\begin{cases}
X & (|j|<M_1)\\
\frac{1}{k} & (M_k \leq |j| < M_{k+1}).
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}